# Can glFenceSync be used cross thread or context boundary?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

May I create a glFenceSync in one thread, and wait for it in another thread?

or

May I create a glFenceSync in one context and wait for it in another context?

Answer (score 3):

> May I create a `glFenceSync` in one thread, and wait for it in another thread?

Every GL function you can call requires you to have made current a GL context for the thread you are calling this, and a GL context can be current to at most one threadt at any point in time.

Technically, the answer to your question is still "yes", since you can issue a `glFenceSync` on one thread, move the context over to another thread and call `gl[Client]WaitSync` there - but that is probably not what you had in mind, and I also don't see an obvious use case for such a pattern.

> May I create a `glFenceSync` in one context and wait for it in another context?

Sync objects are share-able in the GL, so if you create contexts which share objects, they will also share sync objects, and the spec explicitly allows waiting on sync objects of another context. Actually, it is even specified that there can be multiple simultaneous waits on a single sync object, and all of them will be unblocked when the sync object gets signaled (but in an implementation-dependent order).

Comment: thank you, @derhass, I noticed that for EGL there is eglSyncKHR. what are the differences between eglSyncKHR and glFenceSync?

Comment: @DeanSinaean well, that EGL extension is similar in principle to GL's sync objects, but it is a different API level, so it is not limited to OpenGL ES, but can also be used across different khronos APIs, the spec mentions OpenVG explicitly.

Comment: Is there any official/Khronos documentation stating that `glFenceSync` is used to synchronise across threads?