# OpenGLES(3.0) glFinish immediately after FenceSync in multi-threaded

Tags: opengl-es, rendering

The status of multi-threaded rendering OpenGL ES is as follow:

Thread A

```
glBindFrameBuffer(...);
...
glDrawElements(...);
...
GLsync sync = glFenceSync(...);
```

Thread B

```
....
glWaitSync(sync , flags, timeout);
glFlush();
...
```

My question is, if I use glFinish on thread B, will it wait for the commands of thread A to complete?

```
....
glWaitSync(sync , flags, timeout);
glFlush();
glFinish(); // Will it wait for thread A?
...
```

Comment: OpenGL (ES) is not multithread. A [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) can be used in multiple threads, however, it can only be current in one thread at a time. When you make a context current in a thread, this breaks its connection to the thread in which it was previously current. So do you use a shared Context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can glFenceSync be used cross thread or context boundary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61476482/can-glfencesync-be-used-cross-thread-or-context-boundary)

Comment: Different, I understand that fence can be used and synchronized across threads. My question is whether glFinish behind Fence can synchronize another thread. Can the call to glFinish ensure that glDrawElements of thread A is completed?